# factor_cmap in Bokeh is not being applied correctly for categorical chart

Tags: python, pandas, charts, bokeh

I just started learning Bokeh and I am trying to create a strip plot if you will with jitter to show variation over 7 categories where x axis is the error and y-axis is the category. I would like for each category to be a different color.

Seems like factor_cmap is what I should be using under bokeh.transform:
https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/transform.html

The code runs without errors but the colors are never applied (the graph draws with default colors which is blue).

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'E:\Bokeh\Charting\7_vars.csv')
category = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
source = ColumnDataSource(df)
p = figure(width=800, height=800, y_range=category, title="Variation across 7 samples")

p.circle(
    x='Error',
    y=jitter('Category', width=0.6, range=p.y_range),
    source=source,
    fill_color=factor_cmap('Category', palette="Spectral7", factors=category)
)
p.ygrid.grid_line_color = None

show(p)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It is impossible to speculate without knowing moe about the dataframe. A likely explanation is that the field names or categories you supplied to the tranform don't actually match up with the dataframe. You might check your browser's JavaScript console log for messages or errors. All of the actual work (including colormapping) actually happens in the browser, so that is where errors might usually appear.

Comment: Ah! You guys were so right. I was so obsessed with finding issues in the code that I did not even check my DF. There was a typo into the field name in the df indeed! Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine as far as I can tell. Maybe there is a typo somewhere. Could you please show us your DataFrame? Hopefully we can reproduce your problem.

To help you I modified the [`scatter_jitter`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/examples/topics/categorical/scatter_jitter.html) example from the official documentation. I just added `factor_cmap`.

#### Example Code

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.sampledata.commits import data
from bokeh.transform import jitter, factor_cmap
output_notebook()

DAYS = ['Sun', 'Sat', 'Fri', 'Thu', 'Wed', 'Tue', 'Mon']

source = ColumnDataSource(data)

p = figure(
    width=800,
    height=300,
    y_range=DAYS,
    x_axis_type='datetime',
    title="Commits by Time of Day (US/Central) 2012-2016"
)

p.scatter(
    x='time',
    y=jitter('day', width=0.6, range=p.y_range),
    source=source,
    alpha=0.3,
    fill_color=factor_cmap('day', palette='Spectral7', factors=DAYS)
)

p.xaxis.formatter.days = '%Hh'
p.x_range.range_padding = 0
p.ygrid.grid_line_color = None

show(p)
```

#### Output

[image: jitter with factor_cmap]

This was created with bokeh 2.4.3.

Comment: Ah! You guys were so right. I was so obsessed with finding issues in the code that I did not even check my dataframe. There was a typo in the field name in the df indeed! Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question though!