# Bokeh factor_cmap not working for scatter but works for vbar

Tags: python, pandas, charts, bokeh

I am trying to apply a factor_cmap to map simple data points to a scatter plot. I started with a simple [example](https://notebook.community/dennisobrien/bokeh/examples/howto/Categorical%20Data) and tried to modify it and overlay a scatter to test if the same data and color map worked:

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Plot, Scatter
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap
from bokeh import palettes


my_fruits = ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Nectarines', 'Plums', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries']
my_counts = [5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 6]

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(my_fruits=my_fruits, my_counts=my_counts))

p = figure(x_range=my_fruits, plot_height=250, toolbar_location=None, title="Fruit Counts")
p.vbar(x='my_fruits', top='my_counts', width=0.9, source=source,
       line_color='white', fill_color=factor_cmap('my_fruits', palette="Spectral6", factors=my_fruits))
p.scatter('my_fruits', 'my_counts', source=source, size=50, fill_color=factor_cmap('my_fruits', palette="Spectral6", factors=my_fruits), marker="dot", legend_field ='my_fruits')
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.y_range.start = 0
p.y_range.end = 9
p.legend.orientation = "horizontal"
p.legend.location = "top_center"

show(p)
```

The result I get is shown here:
[Result of notebook code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lN6QT.png)
The color mapping works for the bar chart but not for the scatter that is overlaid on it.

What I tried:
I reviewed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75381480/factor-cmap-in-bokeh-is-not-being-applied-correctly-for-categorical-chart) and this asker's issue had to do with their data so I can't tell what the solution was.  I see that the example data can work with a scatter and factor_cmap, but I just can't see why my example won't work.  It seems something about the structure of the data is different but I do not see why the plot behavior is different for scatter and vbar.

What I expected: The scatter plot markers follow colors similar to the vertical bar chart.

What happened: All markers are the same color despite vertical bars following the color map correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The "dot" marker is unique and does not respond to `fill_color`. That is becausue it is usually an addition to some other glyph, e.g. `circle_dot`, `triangle_dot`, and in those cases the "dot" color necessarily has to match the `line_color` not the `fill_color` (otherwise it would be invisible). In order to be consistent everywhere, plain `dot` also just uses `line_color` even when it is on its own:

```py
p.scatter('my_fruits', 'my_counts', source=source, size=50, 
          line_color=factor_cmap('my_fruits', palette="Spectral6", factors=my_fruits), 
          marker="dot", legend_field ='my_fruits')
```

[image]

Alternatively, you could use the "circle" marker instead, which uses both `fill_color` and `line_color` like a typical marker.

Also note that `plot_height` is deprecated, and will need to just be `height` in Bokeh 3.0 and later.